# Select and Update accdb database in ASP.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, ms-access

I am able to select information from my database and retrieve information, but why cant i use the same to update the database?
Commandstring is what i use to write my SQL Sentences.

Not Working:

```
DatabaseConnection.Commandstring = ("UPDATE tbl_login SET Time='"+Settings.UpdateRecord+"' WHERE Username='"+Settings.LoginName+"' ");
```

Connection code:

```
  public static string ConString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("MainData.accdb") + "'; Persist Security Info = False;";
    public static string Commandstring;
    public static object result;

    public static void Connect() {
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(DatabaseConnection.ConString)) {
            con.Open();
            Debug.WriteLine("Connection to DB Established");

            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Commandstring, con)) {
                try {
                   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    con.Close();
                    Debug.WriteLine("Connection to DB Terminated");
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                   Debug.WriteLine("Error Updating Database: " +ex.Message);
                   con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my exception message is saying there is an Syntax error in my Update statement. 
Sending the statement to Debug writeline i get:

```
UPDATE tbl_login SET Time='21' WHERE Username='Bob'
```

Comment: `Time` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#T).  Enclose it in square brackets like this: `UPDATE tbl_login SET [Time]='21' WHERE Username='Bob'`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Time` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#T). Enclose it in square brackets like this:

```sql
UPDATE tbl_login SET [Time]='21' WHERE Username='Bob'
```

I also think you should switch to a parameter query.  But the reserved word issue is the cause of your immediate problem, and will also be an issue in a parameter query.

Comment: Thanks, I have heard that my code was open for SQL Injection attacks, and was going to research this at a later time, thanks for reminding me